# Looking for a simple way to watch files, run a script, and refresh the browser

Tags: linux, windows, bash, macos, watch

File is edited. File is saved. Bash script is run upon save. Browser refreshes itself to automatically show the changes.

Windows, OS X, Linux

Any suggestions?  This seems like such an important thing that's constantly overlooked, and I would greatly appreciate learning how to achieve this between all major OSes.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Well it's pretty simple you'd have to have your client pull changes, or have websocket communication with server, so the server could let you know when files are changed, anyways scripting is involved

Comment: This is for me, not a client.  I use Prepros and Codekit often, but I've been writing a bash script that actually allows plain HTML and CSS to process includes, through a custom framework, without any added code to the page. Atom, along with other popular editors, allows me to automatically run a script after the files are saved.  Now all I'm looking for is a way to watch files and refresh the browser, something that's cross-compatible and vanilla, that i can write myself and understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options. One is to use `entr` on Linux and OSX - website is [here](http://entrproject.org). Then your command is:

```
ls -d * | entr sh -c 'script.bash && reloadbrowser.bash'
```

An alternative to `entr` is to use `fswatch` or `inotifywait` - the syntax is pretty similar. I believe you can use `fswatch` on Windows too.

Then we come onto the question of the browser refresh. It is going to be dependent on the browser and the OS. On OSX, you can use Applescript like this for Safari:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
tell application "Safari"
  set currentURL to URL of current tab of front window
  set URL of current tab of front window to currentURL
end tell
```

And with Google Chrome on OSX, you could use:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
tell application "Google Chrome" to reload active tab of window 1
```

On Linux, you can use `xdotool` as described [here](http://entrproject.org/scripts/reload-browser).

By the way,  on OSX, I would install `entr` and `fswatch`  with `homebrew` using:

```
brew install fswatch
brew install entr
```

Comment: Package managers make me feel like a kid in a candy store. lol  Over 20-years fine-tuning my skills in HTML/CSS/JS has gotten me addicted to 'looking under the hood' for the first time since the BBS scene.  Your assistance is greatly appreciated.  ;)